# Finding a possible path between 2 points with limited circle-ranges (algorithm)

Tags: algorithm, path, shortest-path

I'm currently struggling in finding an algorithm if a path is possible or not.

I have a field of points, the positions of these points are fully random. I have also a starting point, and a destination point. On my starting point I can jump to any point around the starting point in a limited radius, and continue the same from there, but only with a limited amount of jumps. Performance in this case is important! Existant algorithms like Dijkstra won't help me here.

Any idea?

Comment: I think you could use A*, the distance is measured in jumps and the estimation of the minimal distance from a point P to end point E would be ceil(distance(P, E) / radius).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could construct an undirected graph with the points as vertices. Each of the edges connects two points which are no further apart than the jump distance limit. Once this graph is constructed, you can find the shortest path with traditional algorithms.

To construct the graph, you could assign the points to a grid of 2D matrix cells. The cell hight and width is the jump radius limit. Candidate points for an edge for a given point have to belong to its matrix cell or directly adjacent cells. This reduces the construction time.

A further speedup could be to restrict a first version of the graph to those grid cells which are located near the direct line-of-sight between start and end point. Only if the search is not sucessfull, you could broaden the search area and try again.

If start and end point are further apart than radius limit times jump limit, no feasible path exists.

Comment: Yes, but 2 points have an edge if they are not further apart than radius (not jumps). This would be O(n^2).

Comment: @maraca: The proposed heuristics should result in an average runtime lower than quadratic. The worst-case runtime depends on the distribution of the points. Imagine a spiral layout where the spiral lines are too far apart to be connected by a jump.

Comment: So what complexity do you propose? If the spiral is really the worst distribution then it is O(c*n) = O(n), but I'm not entirely sure about that.

Comment: Triangle inequality could also help speed up the construction of the graph; i.e. if |AB| > 2*R, then all points connected to A are not connected to B, and all points connected to B are not connected to A; also, if |AB| > 3*R, no points connected to A are connected to points connected to B, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone want have a solution:
Since the amount of jumps are limited I've created a radial grid, where the maximum radius is the amount of circles multiplied by their own radius.
After that I simply use an A-star path finder. (I used one existant by http://www.rapidfirestudio.com)